# What does "Value does not fall within expected range" mean in runtime error?

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli, speech-recognition, runtime-error

I'm writing a plugin (dll file) using /clr and trying to implement speech recognition using .NET.
But when I run it, I got a runtime error saying "Value does not fall within expected range", what does the message mean?

```
    public ref class Dialog : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
       public: SpeechRecognitionEngine^ sre;

       private: System::Void btnSpeak_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
       {
         Initialize();
       }

       protected: void Initialize()
       {  
          //create the recognition engine
          sre = gcnew SpeechRecognitionEngine();

          //set our recognition engine to use the default audio device
          sre->SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

          //create a new GrammarBuilder to specify which commands we want to use
          GrammarBuilder^ grammarBuilder = gcnew GrammarBuilder();

          //append all the choices we want for commands.
          //we want to be able to move, stop, quit the game, and check for the cake.
          grammarBuilder->Append(gcnew Choices("play", "stop"));

          //create the Grammar from th GrammarBuilder
          Grammar^ customGrammar = gcnew Grammar(grammarBuilder);

          //unload any grammars from the recognition engine
          sre->UnloadAllGrammars();

          //load our new Grammar
          sre->LoadGrammar(customGrammar);

          //add an event handler so we get events whenever the engine recognizes spoken commands
          sre->SpeechRecognized += gcnew EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^> (this, &Dialog::sre_SpeechRecognized);

          //set the recognition engine to keep running after recognizing a command.
              //if we had used RecognizeMode.Single, the engine would quite listening after
          //the first recognized command.
          sre->RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode::Multiple);

          //this->init();
       }  

       void sre_SpeechRecognized(Object^ sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs^ e)
       {
          //simple check to see what the result of the recognition was
          if (e->Result->Text == "play")
          {
             MessageBox(plugin.hwndParent, L"play", 0, 0);
          }

                  if (e->Result->Text == "stop")
          {
             MessageBox(plugin.hwndParent, L"stop", 0, 0);
          }
       }
    };
```

Comment: What is the call stack of the exception?

Comment: Debuggers are your friend - Load it up and find out which line is causing you an issue. without knowing what your input is and how you are passing it in or what your exact output is it is hard to help

Comment: @SLacks: I'm sorry I don't understand your question, I'm new at this kind of programming.

Comment: @Romain: I can't use the debugger since my project does not generate an exe file. Basically, Initialize() will be called when I click a particular button, but even before I started speaking utterances, I got this error. The expected output is a messagebox displaying "play" when I say "play", and "stop" when I say "stop".
Please help me..

Comment: use visual studio to attach to the running process (Debug/Attach to Process...) so you can figure out where the exception is being thrown.

Alternatively, you can catch the exception and display the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what is causing this error.

The error happens at the line

`SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();`

The error means that the input device's channels are out of the range of accepted channels. This is because sometimes on Windows XP an input device has 0 channels. This is a faulty return when called upon, thus leading to an error. This does not mean that the Microphone does not work.

What you can do is first record the input to a wav file, and then recognize the speech from that wav file, like so:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile("input.wav");
```

I hope this resolves the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a Windows Pre-Vista (NT5)...
That error is due to SAPI version is not 5.3 or higher...
Test the code in Windows 7, everything should run OK...

The "Interop" things you are getting relates to the marshalling between native code and .net managed code libraries...

You can see the problem in the library, lines 299 to 325: [Source code for the .NET framework in C#, RecognizerBase.cs source code in C# .NET](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Speech/Src/Recognition/RecognizerBase@cs/1/RecognizerBase@cs).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error a couple of days ago at work. After looking into and debugging a lot I found the following:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fc9ba226-7170-49d8-9fb3-c8de05d5b542/systemspeechrecognition-exception-after-prolonged-use?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Specifically the answer from Zach Barnard is very helpful:

> I may have found a solution to this, though at the sacrifice of Alternates, I set my MaxAlternates to 1, and I haven't had the exception, after running the program for two days. Hopefully this helps someone.

Admittedly I don't fully understand why this exception is thrown. However setting `MaxAlternates` to `1` for your `SpeechRecognitionEngine` object prevents it.

Since the author of the original question never said what the actual problem was, this could be a solution or not.